# font-family change on cordova apache

Tags: android, cordova

It seems font-family css change wont work with Apache Cordova/phonegap in Android. But normal browser have no problems with this, any work around? I'm totally out of solution already.

```
        var y = "Comic Sans MS";

    $(function () {
        $("#changecss").click(function () {
            $('#header').css("font-family", y );
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

If I am not mistaken there are only 3 fonts available on Android by default. If you want to include a different font it needs to be a TrueType font and you'll have to reference the font file yourself.

http://www.brianhadaway.com/font-face-declarations-on-android-devices/

Comment: I did all the reference with the generate version from Font Squirrel. But still android would use the default font. In this case the droid naskh in ice cream sandwich (android 4.x). I would like to debug this, but I don't know how to find this. LogCat or console.log maybe?